# how to fix "txHash: undefined" error using web3.js

Tags: web3js, nodejs

anyone can fix this??

i always got output "txHash: undefined"

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')

const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = newWeb3('https://mainet.infura.io/')

const account1 = '0x9c56de05d7e27bc8.....................'

const account2 = '0xb2269135b0388b6..........................'

const account3 = '0x7717d106658c2................................'

const account4 = '0xb7060b6.............................'

const addresses = [account2, account3, account4];

var i
for (i =1; i < addresses.length; i++) {
  }

const privateKey1 = Buffer.from('4987f2720bcf5e57ad20c60241fcfe1fc1...........', 'hex')

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {

    // Build the transaction
    const txObject = {
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
      to: addresses[i],
      value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1.2', 'ether')),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei'))
    }


    // Sign the transaction
    const tx = new Tx(txObject)
    tx.sign(privateKey1)

    const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
    const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

    // Broadcast the transaction
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
      console.log('txHash:', txHash)
      // Now go check etherscan to see the transaction!
    })
  })
```

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum StackExchange! Did you check what the `err` possibly contains?

Answer (score 1):

`addresses[i]`, which is actually `addresses[3]`, doesn't exist because your array only has tree addresses. Just specifically write a number between 0 and 2 and it will work.

Also, for consistency, make sure to also set a `from` parameter in the `txObject` and do log in the console the error you may get there.

Code:

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')

const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = newWeb3('https://mainet.infura.io/')

const account1 = '0x9c56de05d7e27bc8.....................'

const account2 = '0xb2269135b0388b6..........................'

const account3 = '0x7717d106658c2................................'

const account4 = '0xb7060b6.............................'

const addresses = [account2, account3, account4];

var i
for (i =1; i < addresses.length; i++) {
  }

const privateKey1 = Buffer.from('4987f2720bcf5e57ad20c60241fcfe1fc1...........', 'hex')

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {

    // Build the transaction
    const txObject = {
      nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
      from: account1,
      to: addresses[1],
      value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('1.2', 'ether')),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei'))
    }


    // Sign the transaction
    const tx = new Tx(txObject)
    tx.sign(privateKey1)

    const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
    const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

    // Broadcast the transaction
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
      console.log('err:', err)
      console.log('txHash:', txHash)
      // Now go check etherscan to see the transaction!
    })
  })
```

Comment: can you modify that script here, show me how to do it

Comment: You can recheck the answer now.